# Hibernate POJO mapping to changeable schema

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping, pojo

I know it is not a good practice but there are multiple schemas in DB, but there are same tables in them. So I need to map my POJO as changeable to the schema. Is there any possible approach or application to make it real?

For example; DB2013 and DB2014 are identical as metadata. But there are different datas for the years. So my POJO of a table, say MY_TABLE, I would not like to create new POJO for each DB but I want to make it changeable just before the application starts. So application will be used per schema.

So what is the best solution for this type need?

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "DB2013", name = "MY_TABLE"
public class MyTable {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set up default schema name in JPA configuration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737420/how-to-set-up-default-schema-name-in-jpa-configuration)

Comment: If I put default_schema property, does it put all same schema name to the pojo SQL query strings?

Comment: I tried and it is successful but I realized that the problem isn't that. I need to check it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you use XML configuration you can put placeholders in schema attribute and replace it during compilation by maven. I guess u can do similar thing when using annotation configuration.