# Setting default schema hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

In eclipse I configured a database connection and I set up my JPA project to use it.
In my entity classes, I get the following error:
Schema "ROOT" cannot be resolved for table "XXX"

In the project's JPA settings, there is a check box to "Override default schema from connection" with the schema set to "ROOT" by default.
I can not change that because when I check the checkbox, the schema dropdown is empty.

How do I force eclipse to use the correct schema? What is the correct schema name anyway? I only know the database / catalog name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set up default schema name in JPA configuration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737420/how-to-set-up-default-schema-name-in-jpa-configuration)

Comment: @Arpit Not a duplicate. The question is about Eclipse's, not Hibernate's, default schema. :-)

Comment: What is your database? MySQL? Oracle? Dali (the Eclipse plug-in that provides JPA tooling) depends on DTP (yet another Eclipse plug-in) to provide the metadata used to validate your mappings. Sometimes DTP's handling of various databases can be problematic... Can you see your database/catalog/schema and tables in the Data Source Explorer? This can help us understand how DTP is mapping your database metadata and how we might configure Dali to use it.

Comment: I'm using MySQL. I see the catalog in the Data Source Explorer but no tables.

Comment: I set up a Hibernate Code Generation Configuration (Run->Hibernate Code Generation) and the errors are now gone.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default schema in the JPA properties for hibernate

```
<prop key="hibernate.default_schema">application_schema</prop>
```

Comment: The question is about setting the default for *Eclipse* (not Hibernate).

Comment: Actually the topic for this question clearly says hibernate.