# How to set default schema in JPA

Tags: java, sql, jpa, db2, db-schema

I am working on one application using JPA orm. I need to set default schema in persistence.xml. I got some refence and added properties for default schema which is not working. It is probably some syntax issue or some more mapping\configurations which I am unaware.

Please let me know if any pointers to resolve this issue.

```
<properties>
    <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="supported" />
    <property name="openjpa.jdbc.Schema" value="XY01" />
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="XY01" />
</properties>
```

Comment: The JPA standard file `orm.xml` clearly has a section *persistence-unit-defaults* where you can set the schema. http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_2.xsd  Then there is no need to faff about with JPA provider extensions (and why you would refer to OpenJPA, as well as Hibernate I'm not sure).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up default schema name in JPA configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737420/how-to-set-up-default-schema-name-in-jpa-configuration)

Comment: I mentioned OpenJPA and Hibernet both just to show that I tried both. And I am not using Spring or Hibernet in my project.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What schema is *actually* used when you are using `<property name="openjpa.jdbc.Schema" value="XY01" />`?  Is there a command-line override?  If you are using an IBM-supplied driver, have you tried appending to the URL `currentSchema="XY01"`? If still not resolved then edit your question to give more facts (versions of products, platforms, driver supplier details etc).

Comment: We were referring the existing code base, Hence using the OpenJPA.

Comment: This was part of a migration task. Issue wasn't resolved but this is no longer required. 
Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is no longer required

Answer (score 3):

Try to set the property in your persistence.xml file, as follows:

```
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="myschema"/>
    </properties>
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. This is no longer required now.